# amazon s3 upload file time out

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have a JPG file with 800KB. I try to upload to S3 and keep getting timeout error.
Can you please figure what is wrong? 800KB is rather small for upload.

> Error Message:    Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.
>
> HTTP Status Code: 400
>
> AWS Error Code:   RequestTimeout

```
Long contentLength = null;
System.out.println("Uploading a new object to S3 from a file\n");
try {
    byte[] contentBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
    contentLength = Long.valueOf(contentBytes.length);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.printf("Failed while reading bytes from %s", e.getMessage());
}

ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
metadata.setContentLength(contentLength);        
       
s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, is, metadata));
```

Comment: This happens to me occasionally, and I just retry the upload.

Comment: I get this all the time even with 1KB file upload.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is it possible that IOUtils.toByteArray is draining your input stream so that there is no more data to be read from it when the service call is made?  In that case a stream.reset() would fix the issue.

But if you're just uploading a file (as opposed to an arbitrary InputStream), you can use the simpler form of AmazonS3.putObject() that takes a File, and then you won't need to compute the content length at all.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#putObject(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.io.File)

This will automatically retry any such network errors several times.  You can tweak how many retries the client uses by instantiating it with a ClientConfiguration object.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html#setMaxErrorRetry(int)

Answer (score 1):

If your endpoint is behind a VPC it will also silently error out. You can add a new VPC endpoint here for s3

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/