# Request Time Out Error while uploading to Amazon S3 with InputStream

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file on AMazon S3 using InputStream, My code is as follows and I am getting Request Time out Error, The size of file is very small around 1 MB.

```
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
Long contentLength = Long.valueOf(IOUtils.toByteArray(fis).length);
metadata.setContentLength(contentLength);
try {

    s3Handler.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, s3key, fis,metadata));
} catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
    s3ExceptionHandler.processAmazonServiceException(ase);
} catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
    s3ExceptionHandler.processAmazonClientException(ace);
}
```

Request Time Out:--

```
Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.
Jan 30, 2013 10:15:42 AM javacode.S3ExceptionHandler processAmazonServiceException
SEVERE: HTTP Status Code: 400
Jan 30, 2013 10:15:42 AM javacode.S3ExceptionHandler processAmazonServiceException
SEVERE: AWS Error Code:   RequestTimeout
```

It was working fine when I was using file instead of `inputstream` but the problem is I have only `inputStream` object available.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Look this : [amazon s3 upload file time out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774909/amazon-s3-upload-file-time-out)

Reset your connection after :

Long contentLength = Long.valueOf(IOUtils.toByteArray(fis).length);

fis.reset();

s3Handler.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, s3key, fis,metadata));

It works for me