# Increase write timeout s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using java and PutObjectResult to upload a file on s3 and consistently getting 400 error. Request Timed out. How can I increase the timeout to upload the file.

```
PutObjectResult por = s3Client.putObject(
            new PutObjectRequest(AWS_S3_BUCKET, AWS_S3_FOLDER + "/" + randomFileName,
            inputStream,
            objectMetaData)
            .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [amazon s3 upload file time out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774909/amazon-s3-upload-file-time-out)

Comment: I don't think a longer timeout is possible, since this response appears to be coming from S3 itself... and if it were possible, then I suspect it would not fix the problem you are seeing... which seems likely to be related to how your code is working.

Comment: What's the size of the file you're trying to upload? Have you tried multipart upload, described in the S3 docs?

Comment: I fixed it. There was issue an with the inputstream and buffer. Thanks guys for the help.