# Amazon S3: socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period

Tags: node.js, sockets, amazon-s3

I'm using s3 package to uploading a file to S3: https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3. 
I wrote the following code (based on the code example):

```
var s3 = require('s3');


var client = s3.createClient({
  maxAsyncS3: 20,     // this is the default 
  s3RetryCount: 3,    // this is the default 
  s3RetryDelay: 1000, // this is the default 
  multipartUploadThreshold: 20971520, // this is the default (20 MB) 
  multipartUploadSize: 15728640, // this is the default (15 MB) 
  s3Options: {
    accessKeyId: *****,
    secretAccessKey: ******,
    // any other options are passed to new AWS.S3() 
    // See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html#constructor-property 
  },
});

var params = {
  localFile: "*****",

  s3Params: {
    Bucket: "*****",
    Key: "*****",
    // other options supported by putObject, except Body and ContentLength. 
    // See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property 
  },
};
var uploader = client.uploadFile(params);
uploader.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error("unable to upload:", err.stack);
});
uploader.on('progress', function() {
  console.log("progress", uploader.progressMd5Amount,
            uploader.progressAmount, uploader.progressTotal);
});
uploader.on('end', function() {
  console.log("done uploading");
});
```

I got the following error:

> unable to upload: RequestTimeout: Your socket connection to the server
>   was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle
>   connections will be closed.

Do you have any idea how to solve the problem?

I also reviewed this link: [amazon s3 upload file time out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774909/amazon-s3-upload-file-time-out) , and it didn't help me solve the problem.

Comment: how big is your file ? can you test your code with a small file just to validate your script

Comment: very small. 198 bytes

Comment: I don't know about the 3rd party package - give a try with the official package http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html#Amazon_S3__Create_a_New_Bucket_and_Object__createBucket__upload_

Comment: thanks. It was solved. My problems were:
1. params.s3Params.key has to be the object name in S3. 
2. params.localFile has to be the path to local file I want to upload. If it's a relative path, it has to start with './'